# Responsive Slider image gets overlapped by menu when browser window expands

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Can't seem to source why the image in this full-width slider, when the browser window is fully expanded, gets overlapped slightly by the menu above it.

It looks perfect in mobile, tablet, it's desktop that is posing the problem. Here's a link, open and close the window and you'll see what I mean:

[linked removed]

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was doing some detective work, two things happened, one, I added a fix for a Chrome bug earlier on in the header:

```
body:after {
        display: initial;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

And second, needed to compensate for it with padding:

```
.iosSlider .slider .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Domino effect.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Found it!

---

Ok so when your window is small enough to "qualify" as a mobile device, you have one very important property set on your header:

```
position: static;
```

This means that the header is in the flow of the document. When you change to desktop size, that gets changed to

```
position: fixed;
```

This takes the top header out of the flow of the document, sliding the other content up into its place.

So, to fix this, you can do something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) /*<--your min desktop width here*/
{
    body
    {
        margin-top: 40px; /*header height here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I added that to my child theme's css in firebug it appears to have fixed it however now there's an additional white bar above the menu which is weird?! I should add, it appears at around 1155px width.

Answer (score -1):

use below code in navigation div css file

```
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
```